# JIRA Task and Perforce Job integration connection error - check $P4PORT

Tags: jira, atlassian-fisheye, perforce-integrate

I was trying to configure Perforce Job Integration in JIRA, I was not able to successfully setup connection between JIRA and Perforce Job.
I filled in the fields like p4 Executable, p4port, p4client, p4user, p4password.
However I am getting this following error:

> com.perforce.api.CommitException java.io.IOException: Perforce client
>   error: Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT. TCP connect to
>   rwzinfr1pdv1.wz.hasbro.com failed. A non-recoverable error occurred
>   during a database lookup.

Comment: Please add more details about the error your are getting and provide more material to identify a solution to your problem. It would also be necessary to change the title of this question with a more specific and error-related one.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan Can you please look into this, when I was trying to enable perforce job integration in JIRA, I filled in the fields like p4 Executable, p4port , p4client, p4user, p4password. I am getting this following error. 

com.perforce.api.CommitException java.io.IOException: Perforce client error: Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT. TCP connect to rwzinfr1pdv1.wz.hasbro.com failed. A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.

Comment: I improved your question but I don't know how to fix it. I suggest you to check that your `$P4PORT` value is correctly configured. Let's wait for people competent in this field answer.